# rally wsapi user story change/update release

Tags: rest, rally

I'm having issues trying to get the Rally WSAPI to update the "Release" field via rest calls.

- I know the uri for the Release and user story
- I know the security token
- I am logged in (w/cookie)

URI: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/12341234123&key=mySecurityToken

Sending it the following via POST:

```
{"HierarchicalRequirement":{
    "Release": "/release/12345678901"
}}
```

or

```
{"HierarchicalRequirement":{
    "Release": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/release/12345678901"
}}
```

I'm getting the following response back:

```
{"OperationResult": {
    "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
    "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
    "Errors": [
        "Could not set value for Release: Could not set release for the parent object directly"
    ],
    "Warnings": []
}}
```

Anyone been able to set their userstory to a Release ref object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set a release on a parent story. Parent/epic stories cannot be scheduled for release in UI or in WS API. In UI Release dropdown is grayed out on parent stories.
When I try, I also get

`{"OperationResult": {"Errors": ["Could not set value for Release: Could not set release for the parent object directly"], "Warnings": []}}`

As long as you are setting a release on a leaf story it should work as follows.

Assuming:
your user story ObjectID is 777
your release ObjectID is 888
your valid authentication key is abc123

URL:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v3.0/hierarchicalrequirement/777?key=abc123
```

and Payload:

```
{"HierarchicalRequirement":{
"Release": "/release/888"
}}
```

Comment: Ensure that the target user story (hierarchicalrequirement) does not have children.  You can only change left nodes.

Comment: I meant leaf nodes... not left.